Multiple functions in a single Azure Function App not deploying
I have an Azure Function App with two functions inside running on my local (Mac OS / Visual Studio Code / Node 20 / V4) which works well when tested in the local environment.
However, once is deployed to Azure only works well when specifically pointing the main attribute on package.json to one specific function ( "main": /path/to/function/indexfunction1.js ).
If I specify multiple functions in package.json ( "main": /path/to/function/*.js ), it works well in the local environment but it does not properly deploy the functions in Azure.
ON LOCAL ENVIRONMENT:
[2024-09-19T04:53:13.808Z] Worker process started and initialized.
Functions:
    function1: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/function1

    function2: [PUT] http://localhost:7071/api/function2/{userId}

ON AZURE :
Azure Function App does not show any function available, although the files are present in the app files section.
I would like to have deployed in Azure the Function App containing the two functions, as in my local environment.

I have a default http trigger function and a http trigger function which accepts userId alike you. Code of my second function is given below.
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');

app.http('httpTrigger2', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    route: 'httpTrigger2/{userId}',
    handler: async (request, context) => {
        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);

        const userId = request.params.userId; 
        const name = request.query.get('name') || await request.text() || 'world';

        return { body: `Hello, ${name}! Your user ID is ${userId}` };
    }
});

package.json file for both the functions is given below.
{
  "name": "79005420",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "main": "src/{index.js,functions/*.js}"
}

I have deployed the function successfully to function app.


Try to change "main": "src/{index.js,functions/*.js}" in package.json if its not there by default to get the expected response.


I've already tried "main": "src/functions/*.js" and  "main":"src/functions/{indexfunction1.js,indexfunction2.js}" and they are only recognized on my local environment, but not in Azure once I deploy them.

@RenatoC Can you try main": "src/{index.js,functions/*.js}
